# Passing id in jquery functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass "hitnr" to another function.

Here's how I "get" the number:

```
    $("#HitList").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        generateHitID(18);
    });
```

Here's the part where there's nothing wrong:

```
    function generateHitID(hitnr)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://api.q-music.be/1.2/lists/"+hitnr+"/editions",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(json){
                console.log(json);
                lastEditionID = json.editions.length - 1;
                generateHitPage(json.editions[lastEditionID].id);
                alert(hitnr);
            }
        });
    }
```

**The alert displays 18 here, which is correct.**
But when I try to request it in another function (generateHitPage) something goes wrong..

```
    function generateHitPage(hitnr, editionID)
    {
        urlString = "http://api.q-music.be/1.2/lists/"+hitnr+"/editions/" + editionID;      

                    alert(urlString);
        $.ajax({
            url: urlString,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            success: function(json){
                console.log(json);
ETC.......................
```

The alert becomes: http://api.q-music.be/1.2/lists/340/editions/undefined
**-> The number has changed from 18 to 340 for no reason at all!**

Comment: What is the output from `console.log(json);`? My guess is that `json.editions[lastEditionID].id` is equal to 340.

Comment: I think you need to use `json.list.id` instead of `json.editions[lastEditionID].id`. If you want to pass `18`

Comment: Fixed! I forgot to include "hitnr" in this line:

generateHitPage(hitnr,json.editions[lastEditionID].id);

I can't answer my own question, or mark it has solved, hmm that's annoying.

Comment: @user, you should be able to answer your own question after a slight delay (8 hours IIRC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to pass in the hitnr parameter here:

```
generateHitPage(json.editions[lastEditionID].id);
```

This should be:

```
generateHitPage(hitnr, json.editions[lastEditionID].id);
```

Comment: I've just read the comments, and realized this is an already solved problem. :) Btw you can mark your own questions "solved" by adding an answer, and accepting that.